# How to properly use docker for temporary containers

Tags: docker

I am creating a project correction software that sanboxes for each student their assignments.
I was thinking about docker for doing such mechanism but I am having troubles when using docker CLI.

Must I create an image with a name using `docker build .` before running it ? I would have to remove the image then

I would appreciate any suggestion, thanks

Comment: If you need will need to have temporary container running in a set period of time and wil run to multiple instances e.g. per student, you can create scripts that can be use per student. The script will do build -> run -> test -> terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, docker is a great tool for that task.

Usually, there is no need for you to bother with creating home made scripts to manage several docker containers - this is what docker-compose is for. I use docker-compose even for simple, single container projects, since it encapsulates all the docker CLI arguments into one readable YAML configuration.

As for your actual problem at hand - I am guessing you intend to have one host that runs a container for each student. Here is a starting point dokcer-compose on how I would do it:

```
version: '3'

services:
  sandbox: &sandbox
    image: alpine
    # any additional instructions go here

  student1: *sandbox
  student2: *sandbox
  student3: *sandbox
  student4: *sandbox
  # ...
  # studentN: *sandbox
```

Then, each student needs to:

```
$ cd /the/path/with/docker-compose.yml
$ docker-compose run --rm student2
```

The `--rm` removes the container on exit, so when all students leave, the host will revert to its state before they came in.

Of course, this is an opinion-based question, and there are many different ways to achieve the same (+ depending on your more detailed needs), but in any case, I would exhaust all standard docker/docker-compose approaches before I go look elsewhere.